# Error in Window-Control

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

hi i have some Problem with my Window-Control, if i set the BrowserDialogBox property to True
im becoming an Error Rendering Control - Window1:
"an unhandled exception has occurred object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Synfusion:

```
        <syncfusion:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="250px" 
            Title="Öffnen" IconImageUrl="~/Images/KBD-Favicon.ico" EnableXHTML="False" BrowserDialogBox="true" EnableTheming="true">
        </syncfusion:Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Syncfusion window control as like your code, but it is working without any error which you have reported. Post more of your code and we'll see what you done wrong.

```
<p>
    You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
        title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <syncfusion:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="250px" Title="Öffnen"
            IconImageUrl="~/Images/KBD-Favicon.ico" EnableXHTML="False" InitiallyShown="True"
            BrowserDialogBox="true" EnableTheming="true">
        </syncfusion:Window>
    </asp:Panel>
</p>
```